# Start Windows Service If Replication Fails

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication, ssms

**Setup:**

- We have SQL Server Management Studio 2005 SP3 on all of our Servers.
- We have 1 Main Server, and 1 Secondary Server that has the database from the Main Server being replicated on it. (If it matters, this is a "Pull" replication instead of a "Push" replication)

**Question:**
Is there a way to use the Alerting tools in SSMS 2005 to start a Windows Service on the Secondary Server in the event of Replication Failure?

If not, is this feature available in a newer version of SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of the replication *job* failure, you could respond with an xp_cmdshell statement to perform a Windows function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx

xp_cmdshell needs to be enabled in your Surface Area config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx